# Generating and downloading a CSV from Symfony2

Tags: symfony, csv

I'm trying to create a function in my Symfony project that runs a query on the database based on a search term, retrieves the data then generates a CSV and downloads it. I've followed some guides on how to do this and although the function does not fail, it also does not seem to work.

Here is the function that runs the generate csv:

```
public function exportCSVAction($filter)
{
    $container = $this->container;
    $response = new StreamedResponse(function() use($container,$filter) {

        $em = $container->get('doctrine')->getManager();
        $project_repo = $em->getRepository('AppBundle:Project');

        $results = $project_repo->getSearchResults($filter,true);

        $handle = fopen('php://output', 'w+');

        while (false !== ($row = $results)) {
            fputcsv($handle, $row[0]);
            $em->detach($row[0]);
        }

        fclose($handle);
    });

    $response->headers->set('Content-Type', 'application/force-download');
    $response->headers->set('Content-Disposition','attachment; filename="'.getcwd().'/csv/jobs-export.csv"');

    return $response;

}
```

The `getSearchResults` function in my Repository:

```
public function getSearchResults($filter,$array=false)
{

    $qb = $this->createQueryBuilder('p')
        ->select('p')
        ->leftJoin('AppBundle:Oc73Customer', 'c', 'WITH', 'c.customerId = p.customerId')
        ->leftJoin('AppBundle:Oc73Product', 'pr', 'WITH', 'pr.productId = p.productId')
        ->where('c.firstname LIKE :filter')
        ->orWhere('c.lastname LIKE :filter')
        ->orWhere('pr.model LIKE :filter')
        ->orWhere('p.pONumber LIKE :filter')
        ->setParameter('filter', '%'.$filter.'%');

    if($array == true) {
        return $qb->getQuery()->getArrayResult();
    } else {
        return $qb->getQuery()->getResult();
    }

}
```

As you can see, if `$array` is passed as true, it returns an Array result required for the CSV.

I run the `exportCSVAction` function if a specific query string is passed:

```
if($request->get('export')) {
      $this->exportCSVAction($request->get('s'));
}
```

The page it is run on is a list of projects, and is filtered if the 's' query is passed. If 'export' is also passed it runs the `exportCSVAction` as above.

The function throws no errors, but it just does not download the file - I'm not sure how to debug it since the code is wrapped in a `$response` object, so it doesn't actually run until it gets returned.

If anyone can shed any light on this I would be grateful.

Comment: Why not use xdebug or VarDumper Component?

Answer (score 2):

i used **Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Response;**

here is my ex:

```
<?php

namespace AppBundle\Controller;

use AppBundle\Entity\Customers;
use Sensio\Bundle\FrameworkExtraBundle\Configuration\Route;
use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Controller\Controller;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Response;

class ReportController extends Controller
{
    /**
     * @Route("/report/export_customers_data.csv", name="export_customers_data_csv")
     */
    public function exportCustomersDataCsvAction()
    {

        $customers = $this->getCustomersFromDatabase();

        $rows = array();
        foreach ($customers as $event) {
            $data = array(
                $event->getId(),
                $event->getcustNameOne(),
                $event->getcustNameTwo(),
                $event->getcustAddress(),
                $event->getcustCountry(),
                $event->getcustBusiness(),
                $event->getcustEmail(),
                $event->getcustPhone(),
                $event->getspecialReq()
            );

            $rows[] = implode(',', $data);
        }

        $content = implode("\n", $rows);
        $response = new Response($content);
        $response->headers->set('Content-Type', 'text/csv');

        return $response;


    }


    public function getCustomersFromDatabase()
    {
        $customers = $this->getDoctrine()
            ->getRepository('AppBundle:Customers')
            ->findAll();

        return $customers;
    }

}
```

when i call "/report/export_customers_data.csv" the download is starting automaticaly

Comment: Please add some explanation to what is this code supposed to do and how does it work with the stated problem.

Answer (score 0):

Can you try something like this?

```
$response->headers->set('Content-Encoding', 'UTF-8');
$response->headers->set('Content-Type', 'text/csv; charset=UTF-8');
$response->headers->set('Content-Disposition', 'attachment; filename=sample.csv');

return $response;
```

The problem might be here: filename="'.getcwd().'/csv/jobs-export.csv"'
A string is expected, the file name...not a relative path.

Comment: I tried this, but still it does nothing when I load the page. There's definitely a return but it seems like it's not even doing whats in the StreamedResponse

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```
$response->headers->set('Content-Type', 'text/csv');
$response->headers->set('Content-Disposition','attachment; filename="sample"');
```

You don`t need

```
$response->headers->set('Content-Type', 'application/force-download');
```